# Configuring CodeClimate test coverage with TravisCI on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

Relevant lines of my .travis.yml file, which I got from the sample here:
https://docs.codeclimate.com/v1.0/docs/travis-ci-test-coverage

```
env:
  global:
    - CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID=MY_ACTUAL_ID

services:
  - postgresql

before_script:
  - curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-darwin-amd64 > ./cc-test-reporter
  - chmod +x ./cc-test-reporter
  - ./cc-test-reporter before-build
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres

script:
  - bundle exec rake db:migrate
  - bundle exec rspec

after_script:
- ./cc-test-reporter after-build --exit-code $TRAVIS_TEST_RESULT
```

Error:

```
$ ./cc-test-reporter before-build
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 57: ./cc-test-reporter: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
The command "./cc-test-reporter before-build" failed and exited with 126 during .
```

Thanks

**Solved:**

I realized that while my development machine may be MacOS, the TravisCI environment is on Linux.

Changing test-reporter URL to https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that while my development machine may be MacOS, the TravisCI environment is on Linux.

Changing test-reporter URL to https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

The latest version 0.9.0 on linux is throwing the same format error.

[The executable has been compiled incorrectly](https://github.com/codeclimate/test-reporter/issues/449).

As a workaround you can use the previous version:

```
curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-0.7.0-linux-amd64 > ./cc-test-reporter
```